# Python: openpyxl change cell fill to 'none' and borders to 'none'

Tags: python, excel

I've got an Excel document that I'm trying to remove formatting (any cell coloring / borders) on 2 sheets; 'Table' & 'Test'.

I've looked through all the documentation on PatternFill, but I only see how to apply colors/formatting and not how to reset them to null.

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A [`PatternFill`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.fills.html#openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill) object with argument `fill_type=None` has to be created in order to get no cell color. Below is a code snippet for stripping all cells in an existing excel workbook of color and borders:

```
import openpyxl

# Load workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')

# Initialize formatting styles
no_fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(fill_type=None)
side = openpyxl.styles.Side(border_style=None)
no_border = openpyxl.styles.borders.Border(
    left=side, 
    right=side, 
    top=side, 
    bottom=side,
)

# Loop through all cells in all worksheets
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    for row in sheet:
        for cell in row:
            # Apply colorless and borderless styles
            cell.fill = no_fill
            cell.border = no_border

# Save workbook
wb.save('workbook_modified.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hey Xukaro, thanks for the reply. I see what you're saying; the PatternFill object needs to get created first, then applied to each cell. I thought there would be a VBA style way to do it at the sheet level, and not the individual cell level.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solutions:

```
cell.value = None
cell.border = None # Border() more recommended
cell.fill = PatternFill()
```